# Should a primary key in a table be a user-defined string or a UUID?

Tags: nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I am working on an app where users will be able to create listings for sale.
My table will hold data like: a title (string), a category (string), the price (number) and some other that are not as important.

I also need a slug for the URLs, so my question is: **Should I store the slug as the primary key (ID) or put it as a Global Secondary Index?**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you gauarantee that the slug will be unique and never changing? If so you can probably use it as a PK.

That means that when you generate the slug based on customer input you have to test that an item with that slug doesn't already exist. If it does you fail the request and ask the user to provide a different value. Do that until you get a successful insert.